# update a fragment on ViewPager based on the fragment before

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am using ViewPager with fragments and a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, i need update my second fragment based on what the user checked in the first one, what happens is that both fragments are loaded when the fragment activity is started, so doesn't matter what the user checks on the first fragment, the second will not get updated. i've tried to override de getItemPosition with the notifyDataSetChanged for call a method to update my fragment, but it appears to be called just when it's created, i need update the second fragment when the user check the options that he want in the first fragment. Thanks

```
public class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {        

   public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if(mFragments.get(position) instanceof UpdateableFragment){
                 notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            return mFragments.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragments.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
            if (object instanceof UpdateableFragment) {
                ((UpdateableFragment) object).customize();
            }

            return super.getItemPosition(object);
        }
    }
```